# Passing data from csv file to existing foreach loop in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I have this foreach loop that will iterate value from filename and data and pass it to existing template

```
foreach($file in Get-ChildItem path\ -Filter *.txt){
  foreach ($line in $file |Get-Content){
        @"
group {1}
name {0} 
realname {0}
"@ -f $line,$file.BaseName
    }
}
```

{1} is filename and {0} is data from line of every file.

Now I need to pass second value from different csv file that looks something like this

```
group1,671
group2,672
......
```

How do I pass value from second place of the csv file (671, 672) to existing script providing the first string (group1, group2) is same value as filename {1} so it will look like this in the script

```
foreach($file in Get-ChildItem path\ -Filter *.txt){
  foreach ($line in $file |Get-Content){
        @"
group {1}
name {0} 
realname {0}
name {0}  id:{2}
"@ -f $line,$file.BaseName
    }
}
```

Value of {2} must correspond with the value of {1} in main file. Eg : group1.txt contains this

```
user1
```

Returning template should give this output

```
group group1 ({1} from main file)
name user1 ({0} from main file) 
realname ({0} from main file) 
name ({0} from main file)  id:671({2} integer/2nd place from cvs file)
```

Value of {2} in this case is 671 because the in csv file it is the integer from line containing filename(group1),id

In short the logic should be

```
If {1} = first string from csv file, {2} = 2nd place/integer in csv file
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code shows that the group names are in fact the same as the file's BaseName.

In order to add the matching values from the second file, you can do this:

```
# read the data from the second csv
$groupCsv = Import-Csv -Path 'path\to\the\second\file' -Header Group, Id
# create a hashtable from this data for fast lookup
$groups = @{}
$groupCsv | ForEach-Object { $groups[$_.Group] = $_.Id }

$template = @"
group {1}
name {0} 
realname {0}
name {0}  id:{2}
"@

foreach($file in Get-ChildItem 'path' -Filter *.txt) {
    foreach ($line in $file | Get-Content ) {
        $template -f $line, $file.BaseName, $groups[$file.BaseName]
    }
}
```

Comment: Group names and file's BaseName are the same because it's done on purpose so it can be used as a condition before parsing the value. Anyway, I tried your code but it's returned Cannot index into a null array error. I think there is a problem with this line $groups = $groupCsv | ForEach-Object { $group[$_.Group] = $_.Id } based on the error message.

Comment: @wdzww Ah, sorry, I made a mistake there. Fixed now.

Comment: Thanks Theo but its returning empty value. Perhaps because I'm not clear with my question. I've updated the question to further clarify the requirement.

Comment: @wdzww Now you really got me confuzed.. This is exactly what the code does, provided the second CSV file is what you say it is. Please edit the question again and show the (sanitized) lines of that file as-is. Does it have headers already or not?